# taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php being ignored

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have been trying to theme my taxonomy page output following this tutorial

http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode31

The tutorial suggest using taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php to override the default output and embed a view.

Unfortunately I have not been successful.  It seems that taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php is totally ignored.

I thought I had a solution when I started using page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php instead, this seems to get picked up however $tid is not passed to this template so I am unable to pull the taxonomy items.

I am using drupal 6.26.

**EDIT**

According to the video tutorial

Step 1) Create a blank file named taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php within theme folder

Step 2) Navigate to a taxonomy page.  This should produce a page (with headers and footers) but no actual content, since taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php overrides the taxonomy output and this file is currently empty.

It is at Step 2 that I am stuck.  The taxonomy pages return a page filled with taxonomy nodes, it seems that taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php is being ignored.  I have flushed all caches and I cannot seem to figure out what is outputting the current content.

**SOLUTION (a bad one)**

Since I have spent so much time on this I decided to scrap the idea of using taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php because in my setup it simply wasn't overriding the taxonomy pages.

Instead I am using page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php which does override the taxonomy pages in my setup.  However the downside to this is that this template does not have $tids available to use as required by the tutorial.  So to get this I have used the following code in page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php

```
$splode=explode("/",$_GET['q']);
$tids[]=$splode[2];
```

It essentially takes the query string in the url which looks like taxonomy/term/10.  Then explodes the string by slashes and uses the last portion for it's tid.

It's nasty, disgusting, but I'm in a rush. If anyone has a better solution, I'd love to know.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Rather than expecting people to view an entire video to understand your question, it will help you get a better/quicker answer if you actually summarise the steps you've taken in the question body itself.

Comment: Hi Clive, sorry about that. Added some extra detail, hopefully that will help.

Comment: https://groups.drupal.org/node/43398 you check out the comments in this link. "taxonomy_term (default)" view enabled was preventing the taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php from being processed. Once we disabled the taxonomy_term view the override page used in the Mustardseed demo began working and all was well.

Comment: @MohammedShameem thanks, however I had already tried that.  This view is already disabled in my setup, so something else is causing the problem.  Is there a way I can see what is generating the current page?

Comment: You can install the devel module and there is a devel theme module which tells you which all theme files are being used.

Comment: @MohammedShameem Thanks again.  I have this module installed but it doesn't seem to appear in my theme.  I have tried something else.  In page.tpl.php I put `<?php print '<pre>' . print_r(get_defined_vars()) . '</pre>';?>`. I see `Array ( [template_file] => sites/all/themes/murad2013/templates/page.tpl.php [variables] => Array ( [template_files] => Array ( [0] => page-taxonomy [1] => page-taxonomy-term [2] => page-taxonomy-term-10 )` taxonomy_term_page.tpl.php does not appear.  tid is also unavailable unless I parse it from 'page-taxonomy-term-10' but that seems like a bad hack